# Javascript Sendgrid Error Missing Variable Require

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sendmail

I am trying to send an email from sendgrid but whenever I try to run the function it returns "Can't find variable: require". I have looked online and cannot find a solution to the issue. This is the sample code that mine is based on. Please help

```
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')('YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY');
sendgrid.send({
  to:       'example@example.com',
  from:     'other@example.com',
  subject:  'Hello World',
  text:     'My first email through SendGrid.'
}, function(err, json) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: Are you running this in the browser or the server?

Comment: I think the server, Im not really sure to be honest

Comment: The code example you posted requires you to be running that code on a nodejs server.

Answer (score 0):

require is a keyword for the [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) framework. Have you referenced this library on your page?

Comment: I referenced require.js and it still says that it cant find the variable require.